# PostGIS layer displays correctly in QGIS, generates error in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, arcgis-10.5

I have a road centerline layer in PostGIS that displays correctly in QGIS 2.18.10, but errors in ArcMap 10.5.1 with

> The specified coordinate exceeds the valid coordinate range

Other PostGIS layers show correctly in ArcMap.

What is wrong with this road centerline layer that ArcMap doesn't like but QGIS doesn't mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source dataset (file geodatabase feature class -> shapefile) had Z and M values, which when loaded into PostGIS tripped up ArcGIS but not QGIS. I removed the Z and M values from the source dataset, reimported it into PostGIS, and now the dataset displays correctly in ArcMap with no errors.

Esri support: "How To: Remove Z- and/or M-values from a feature class":

http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010389